# How to disable iframes in browsers

Tags: browser, iframe

I'm currently using Chrome 27.

After looking through the settings options (*Settings →  Privacy → Content settings*) I see that I can disable just about anything... except iframes.

Is there any easy way to do this? Is it also possible in IE and Firefox?

Comment: Why would you disable iframes?

Comment: There's a particular site which has useful content for me, however the iframe content / advertisements contains contains content that i'd rather not see. So i only need this on a temporary basis.

Comment: So you actually want to block iframes on a specific site?

Comment: well yes, maybe a couple of sites

Comment: You should be able to create an AdBlock filter for that.

Comment: hmmm i don't have the adblock extension installed... if there's no other way then i'll try that out

Comment: Strange though, there are built-in options to block images, plugins (like flash) etc, why not iframes - which are generally associated with ads and sometimes quite annoying

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using the extension "stylish"

It lets you target particular urls and then you can add custom styles for that website.

Here's [a post in Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17143095/703717) which illustrates this.

So in my case I added the following custom css for the particular website i needed to target

```
iframe
{
  display: none;
}
```

... and it works great!

Comment: What’s the point in doing this? The javascript in iframes will still execute.

Comment: As i mentioned in the comments on the question, I just want to hide the content of the iframes on a particular website. It's not a security concern here

Comment: There’s no point in doing this

Comment: It is indeed useful for hiding the iframe. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: The point is, when an ugly iframe is overlapping the main content on a poorly designed website. Don't question the usefulness, just that there's one person who needs it!

Answer (score 2):

Just remove all elements that are iframes with javascript directly in the console

or install a plugin for a more permanent solution like: [noscript](https://noscript.net/)

## Temporary fix

### One Line:

```js
(function(){var f=document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");for(var i in f)try{f[i].parentNode.removeChild(f[i]);}catch(e){console.error(e);}})();
```

This will permanently remove the iframes on page. (until the page is refreshed)

To use this live

- open console (<kbd>F12</kbd> key)
- navigate to the console tab
- paste the one line or the human code into the

  ```
  >
  ```

  field and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

### Human code:

```js
(function(){
var listOfFrames = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");

while (listOfFrames /*exists*/ && (listOfFrames.length > 0) ) {
  try {
    for (var iterator in listOfFrames) {
      listOfFrames[iterator]                  // get the next frame
      .parentNode                             // find the parent 
      .removeChild( listOfFrames[iterator] ); // remove the frame from the parent
    }
  }catch(e){                                  // we found a frame that no longer exists
    console.error(e);
  }
  var listOfFrames = 
     document.getElementsByTagName("iframe"); // update the list regardless of errors in case we missed one
}                                             // loop again unless the condition is satisfied
})();                                         // end of call of the function
```

### Before you try this

If you don't know your browser's behavior around loops and removing elements make sure everything is **saved** locally or on the server before you start. Running the code **might remove** your work. Be sure that you will be okay if your **browser crashes**.

I edited this because I didn't think it was readable hopefully it's better.

Comment: Minor note: I'd expect the `try...catch` around the `f[i] .parentNode .removeChild(f[i])` to ensure others are still deleted.

Comment: Thanks for you're input @Arjan I'll add a tweak that works a bit better, to my answer.

Comment: Won't this lead to an infinite loop if removing one of the iframes fails (and keeps failing)?

Comment: @Venryx It might be possible... the need for the try catch was from iframes that were nested and therefore already deleted. I don't know if `removeChild` can fail any other way. If it can then there would be an event queue feedback. As I don't think removeChild can fail any other way, I don't think it can happen.